# Sharepoint and SSRS report trust relationship ssl/tls secure channel remote certificate is invalid

Tags: ssl, sharepoint-2010, ssrs

I have no experience with sharepoint at all. but this is what I observed.

I intermittently getting this error message on my sharepoint. 
could not establish trust relationship for the ssl/tls secure channel. Remote Certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Screnshot of the error
(I altered the URL because I can't have more than two links so please add dot com on the URL) i.imgur com/36kAWcS.png

This is how the sharepoint page layout.

1. I have report.aspx. and below is the content of the aspx file.
2. The url is http://sharepoint.COMPANY.com/Pages/Report.aspx.
3. The URL is intranet only.
4. The sharepoint is hosted in SERVER1 and the SSRS is hosted in
   SERVER.
5. I observed this error happens on both HTTP and HTTPS
   http sharepoint COMPANY com/Pages/Report.aspx
   OR 
   https   sharepoint COMPANY com/Pages/Report.aspx

So far, the step I did was to follow this blog
http://krishnasangani.blogspot.ca/2013/06/the-remote-certificate-is-invalid.html
Restarted IIS in SERVER1 AND SERVER2. but the problem persist. 
Another I have done is to click the certificate in internet explorer and everything looks ok on that side to (certificate is valid)

It seems to only happen earlier during the morning, then it fixes itself around 9 Oclock. It has been on going for about 2 weeks. Please help troubleshooting this.

```
<%@ Page Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing.TemplateRedirectionPage,Microsoft.SharePoint.Publishing,Version=14.0.0.0,Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bsasdasdasd9c" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~TemplatePageUrl" %> <%@ Reference VirtualPath="~masterurl/custom.master" %><%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bsasdasdasd9c" %>
<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:547SF010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00457845FFSW"><head>
<!--[if gte mso 9]><SharePoint:CTFieldRefs runat=server Prefix="mso:" FieldList="FileLeafRef,Comments,PublishingStartDate,PublishingExpirationDate,PublishingContactEmail,PublishingContactName,PublishingContactPicture,PublishingPageLayout,PublishingVariationGroupID,PublishingVariationRelationshipLinkFieldID,PublishingRollupImage,Audience,PublishingPageImage,PublishingPageContent,SummaryLinks,ArticleByLine,ArticleStartDate,PublishingImageCaption,HeaderStyleDefinitions"><xml>
<mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
<mso:PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">8</mso:PublishingContact>
<mso:HeaderStyleDefinitions msdt:dt="string"></mso:HeaderStyleDefinitions>
<mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact msdt:dt="string">First Last Name</mso:display_urn_x003a_schemas-microsoft-com_x003a_office_x003a_office_x0023_PublishingContact>
<mso:PublishingContactPicture msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactPicture>
<mso:PublishingContactName msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactName>
<mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x010100C568DB5SDH48375LKNSDFG8340JKRG8034U6NEGK8TNGE8U34NIOGE8355H3358TRNG38G43JIOEG0T3JIGE9034340R8J05T4I54T4J8903HH5640K9445G54HH6564H65665</mso:ContentTypeId>
<mso:Comments msdt:dt="string"></mso:Comments>
<mso:PublishingContactEmail msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingContactEmail>
<mso:PublishingPageLayout msdt:dt="string">https://sharepoint.COMPANY.com/_catalogs/masterpage/PageFromDocLayout.aspx, Body only</mso:PublishingPageLayout>
<mso:PublishingPageContent msdt:dt="string">&lt;div class=&quot;ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read a74e0591-4ee6-4837-935a-3c932a967fac&quot; id=&quot;div_a74e0591-4ee6-4837-935a-3c932a967fac&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div id=&quot;vid_a74e0591-4ee6-4837-935a-3c932a967fac&quot; style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div class=&quot;ms-rtestate-read ms-rte-wpbox&quot;&gt;&lt;div class=&quot;ms-rtestate-notify  ms-rtestate-read e97fce7c-b702-4530-ae50-16ea77475fd5&quot; id=&quot;div_e97fce7c-b702-4530-ae50-16ea77475fd5&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
&lt;div id=&quot;vid_e97fce7c-b702-4530-ae50-16ea77475fd5&quot; style=&quot;display:none&quot;&gt;&lt;/div&gt;&lt;/div&gt;
</mso:PublishingPageContent>
<mso:PublishingRollupImage msdt:dt="string"></mso:PublishingRollupImage>
<mso:RequiresRouting msdt:dt="string">False</mso:RequiresRouting>
</mso:CustomDocumentProperties>
</xml></SharePoint:CTFieldRefs><![endif]-->
<title>Report</title></head>
```

A few questions I have in mind is
Any pointer to troubleshoot this problem 
AND
By looking at the ASPX file, Would you be able to determine what method is my Sharepoint page calling the SSRS report , integrated mode, native mode? IEFrame? The reason I am asking this is that maybe IF I google using the right terminology I can get to the similar problem and solution.

Thanks

in sharepoint error log I found the folowing 
SharePoint Critical An operation failed because the following certificate has validation errors:\n\nSubject Name: CN=*.COMPANY, OU=Domain Control Validated, O=*.COMPANY.com\nIssuer Name: SERIALNUMBER=00, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority, OU=http:// certificates godaddy com/repository, O="GoDaddy com, Inc.", L=Scottsdale, S=Arizona, C=US\nThumbprint: A998EF22\n\nErrors:\n\n NotTimeValid: A required certificate is not within its validity period when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in the signed file.

Comment: We found in SERVER1 IIS an expired certs.

I was folowing this steps
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Administrative Tools.

 1. Right-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and select
    Run as administrator.
 2. In the Connections pane on the left, select the computer that
    contains the site.
 3. In Features View, select Server Certificates.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378790(v=ws.10).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a description in error log in this location
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\LOGS
the error is:

> SharePoint Critical An operation failed because the following
>   certificate has validation errors:\n\nSubject Name: CN=.COMPANY,
>   OU=Domain Control Validated, O=.COMPANY.com\nIssuer Name:
>   SERIALNUMBER=00, CN=Go Daddy Secure Certification Authority,
>   OU=http:// certificates godaddy com/repository, O="GoDaddy com, Inc.",
>   L=Scottsdale, S=Arizona, C=US\nThumbprint: A998EF22\n\nErrors:\n\n
>   NotTimeValid: A required certificate is not within its validity period
>   when verifying against the current system clock or the timestamp in
>   the signed file.

with that above info I managed to google to the right area

We found in SERVER1 IIS an expired certs.

I was folowing this steps
Click Start, click Control Panel, and then click Administrative Tools.

1. Right-click Internet Information Services (IIS) Manager and select
   Run as administrator.
2. In the Connections pane on the left, select the computer that
   contains the site.
3. In Features View, select Server Certificates.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd378790(v=ws.10).aspx